# Return only the property of enum, not Class.Property

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I have the following code:

```
from enum import Enum

class BetterChoices(Enum):
    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        return [(tag.name, tag.value) for tag in cls]


class SensorStatus(BetterChoices):
    UNASSIGNED =  'Sin asignar'
    ASSIGNED =  'Asignado'
```

If I do `print(SensorStatus.ASSIGNED.name)` it returns `SensorStatus.ASSIGNED`. If I do `print(SensorStatus.ASSIGNED.value)` it returns `'Sin asignar'`. What if I just want to return the name, not the `Class.name`?

So, if I do `print(x)` it will return `ASSIGNED` as a string.

Comment: [When I test it](https://ideone.com/cn60Im), an enum object's `name` doesn't include the class name.

Comment: Even testing with the exact enum classes you used, [`print(SensorStatus.ASSIGNED.name)` prints `ASSIGNED`](https://ideone.com/1xMOB2), not `SensorStatus.ASSIGNED`.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce this. `print(SensorStatus.ASSIGNED.name)` prints `ASSIGNED`. `print(SensorStatus.ASSIGNED)` prints `SensorStatus.ASSIGNED` - are you sure you didn't do this by accident? This behaviour is [well-documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum)

Comment: I don't know, when I'm using your compiler @user2357112supportsMonica i get the same result as you. I'll delete the question, since it seems I can't reproduce the behavior described in the question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by implementing the `__str__` magic method in your `BetterChoices` class:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Each python object has string representation. When you do `str(object)` or `print(object)` Python implicitly calls `object.__str__`. `Enum`'s default string representation  has form `<Classname>.<Attribute>`. To override that you just need implement your own version of `__str__`.

Comment: that's the right answer! can you explay a little bit more on it?

Comment: it seems i can't reproduce the behavior, and the comments above are right